# How to print a 40 bit number in PHP using a 32 bit machine

Tags: php, windows, function, hex, decoding

I'm trying to print a 40 bit number in php. But when using a Windows machine, it only allows for 32 bit integers which is causing my code echo the wrong result. Example of the code below:

```
function decoded_microchip_id($coded_string) {
     $manufacturer = substr($coded_string, 0, 3);
     $manufacturer = hexdec($manufacturer);
     $manufacturer = $manufacturer / 4;
     $device_id = substr($coded_string, 2, 11);
     $device_id = hexdec($device_id);
     $device_id = $device_id & 0x3fffffffff;
     echo $manufacturer.'.'.$device_id;
};

decoded_microchip_id('f58e29a43c67');
```

The correct output for the code above is: 982.60828171367

But in my 32 bit Windows environment I'm getting: 982.698629223

When testing the code in various PHP sandbox's the output varies as well.

Here is an example of a sandbox environment giving me the correct output:
http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/83cc28fd5314557e7a9d86d8061e1c8dfae4d1b7

And here is an example of an environment that produces the wrong output:
http://codepad.org/m2ygOgC6

Does anybody know a way around this issue or a solution.

Thanks.

Comment: And how do you think 8bit microcontrollers can handle 32 or 64 bit integers??.... by splitting!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The PHP function [`hexdec()`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.hexdec.php) works fine on 32-bit too. The documentations says it produces `float` numbers when the result doesn't fit in 32 bits.

It's interesting that `0x3fffffffff` is also stored as a `float` number.

The culprit is the bitwise operator (`&`) that seems to produce an integer number. Converting its result to float doesn't help, the damage is already done.

This behaviour is [documented](http://php.net/manual/en/language.operators.bitwise.php):

> both operands will be converted to integers and the result will be an integer.

#### A potential solution

You can try to split the input string in pieces that fit in 32 bits and use bitwise operators on them then use addition and multiplication to generate the final value (addition and multiplication convert the result to float if it cannot fit in 32 bits).

#### A concrete solution

A simpler solution for this situation is to convert the hex string to the binary representation of the number it encodes, extract the bits you need for each component then convert the values to decimal. No bit operations are involved in this case (except for the conversions but those seem to work correctly).

```
function decoded_microchip_id($coded_string)
{
    // Convert to binary
    $bin = base_convert($coded_string, 16, 2);
    // Split to 10/38 bits
    $manufacturer = substr($bin, 0, 10);
    $device_id    = substr($bin, 10, 38);
    // Convert to decimal
    $manufacturer = bindec($manufacturer);
    $device_id    = bindec($device_id);
    // Put pieces back
    return $manufacturer.'.'.$device_id;
}
```